# logic app standard - managed identity connection NOT visible

Tags: azure-logic-app-standard

I'm creating Azure logic app standard, However, in logic app standard I'm unable to see the option to create managed identity connection for Azure Blob Storage.
I have enabled Identity and added a contributor role to the Azure storage.
[image]

Can someone please suggest, how I can achieve managed identity in logic app standard to Azure Storage (Blob). Thanks, Deepak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can able to find it under the **Azure >> When a blob is added or modified (properties only) (V2)**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you have shown in your 2nd screenshot there is a drop-down available to select the managed identity, but I dont have this drop-down, please refer to my screenshot, I only have the option for connection string only... wondering why!!

Comment: As I have mentioned, Instead of using Built-in blob trigger try using Azure blob trigger i.e., Instead of https://i.imgur.com/k44Z8dt.png use https://i.imgur.com/x7DM5Ks.png